# How to get Decimal Part Of float number

Tags: java

How to get the decimal part of floating number as decimal in Java?

Like If `float f=2.34;`

Then `decimal part=34;`

Comment: Not only is this question a duplicate, it is unclear what you want. Let's say the input is 0.015: should the result be a String ("015")? Or a number of hundredths, truncated (1)? Or a number of hundredths, rounded up (2)? It's important to be specific so you don't waste the time of everyone involved.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
float f=2.34;
float deci = (f - (int)f)*(Math.Pow(10,getDecimalPlaces(f));

getDecimalPlaces(Float f) {
   String txt = Float.toString(f):
   int integerPlaces = txt.indexOf('.'); 
   int decimalPlaces = txt.length() - integerPlaces - 1;
   return decimalPlaces;
}
```

Comment: this will give 0.34... but she is asking for 34

Comment: agreed, I have changed it now

Comment: but this is not a generic solution... what if there is only one decimal value... like 2.3

Comment: You are right, please see now?

Comment: your solution might work... but I feel it's too complicated... I was working on a simpler solution... take a look at it... I'm posting

Comment: This code will work for any number of decimal digits.

    float f = 2.3445f;
    String s = Float.toString(f);
    char[] c = s.toCharArray();
    int length = s.length();
    int flag = 0;
    StringBuilder n = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(flag == 1)
        {
            n.append(c[i]);
        }
        if(c[i] == '.')
        {
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
    String result = n.toString();
    int answer = Integer.parseInt(result);
    System.out.println(answer);

Comment: feel free to copy and use it

Comment: Yes sure, will have a look at it

Comment: String s= "12.34";
  String fraction = "";
  
  fraction = "0."+s.split("\\.")[1];
  System.out.println(fraction);

Answer (score 0):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
    public static String getDecimalPart(double number, int numOfDigits){

        return String.format("%."+numOfDigits+"f", number-(int)number);
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(getDecimalPart(2.454,2));
    }
}
```